# Python. How to optimize set of classes?

Tags: python

I have following:

```
class DepartmentsSet(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MODELS_NS

    service_difference_set = Iterable(Department)
    db_difference_set = Iterable(Department)
    intersection_difference_set = Iterable(Department)

    def __init__(self, service_diff, db_diff, intersection):
        self.service_difference_set = _convert_to_departments(service_diff)
        self.db_difference_set = _convert_to_departments(db_diff)
        self.intersection_set = _convert_to_departments(intersection)


def _convert_to_departments(operation_set):
    departments = []
    for item in operation_set:
        department = dict(item)
        departments.append(Department(
            name=department.get('name'),
            external_id=department.get('external_id')
        ))


class EmployeesSet(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = MODELS_NS

    service_difference_set = Iterable(Employee)
    db_difference_set = Iterable(Employee)
    intersection_set = Iterable(Employee)

    def __init__(self, service_diff, db_diff, intersection):
        self.service_difference_set = _convert_to_employees(service_diff)
        self.db_difference_set = _convert_to_employees(db_diff)
        self.intersection_set = _convert_to_employees(intersection)


def _convert_to_employees(operation_set):
    employees = []
    for item in operation_set:
        employee = dict(item)
        dep = employee.get('department')
        employees.append(Employee(
            name=employee.get('name'),
            post=employee.get('post'),
            department=(dep.name if isinstance(dep, CompanyDepartment) else u''),
            contact_info=employee.get('contact_info'),
            external_id=employee.get('external_id')))
    return employees
```

I have two questions:

1. So, as you can see my classes `DepartmentsSet` and `EmployeesSet` both have similar structure. The only difference between them is that their sets consist of `_convert_to_departments` or `_convert_to_employees`.
   I realize that my solution is not good. What's the best practices for this case?
2. Is there any way to unify functions `_convert_to_departments` and `_convert_to_employees` into general one?

*I can't make single class for DepartmentsSet and EmployeesSet as these classes would be types of my SOAP service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your direct questions is simple - move common code and variables to a superclass and inherit EmployeeSet and DepartmentSet from it like so:

```
class CommonModel(ComplexModel):

    def get_items(self, operation_set):
        items = [dict(x) for x in operation_set]
        return items

    # important: put COMMON methods, variables etc. here 

class DepartmentsSet(CommonModel):

    ...
    def _convert(self, operation_set):
        items = self.get_items(operation_set)
        for item in items:
            ... # convert to departments

class EmployeeSet(CommonModel):

    ...
    def _convert(self, operation_set):
        items = self.get_items(operation_set)
        for item in items:
            ... # convert to employees
```

However, strategically I feel that's not a good design really, if it's truly the case that "The only difference between them is that their sets consist of ", isn't `DepartmentSet` and `EmployeeSet` really the same thing? Could you not make it a single class with 2 conversion methods for instance?

That's still not quite good design though - you're mixing up collections and specific objects in a class. That's really a violation of Single Responsibility Principle. Make `Employee` or `Department` or `CommonModel` a single class and simply put their instances in lists. If you really, really need to convert somewhere provide a single object conversion method, and then you can do stuff like:

```
[x.convert() for x in list_of_model_instances]
```

..without even bothering to check what's the class of `x` (that's duck typing).

I still don't think you do really, it should be some other class or function that can take an instance of `CommonModel` on input and do whatever it wants with it. If you really need to do elaborate conversion, why not make a `Converter` class that can take a number of input instances and output whatever it is asked for? (that goes along Single Responsibility Principle)

BTW, if you do that you could make ComplexModel be an abstract base class or inherit from it, like so:

```
class AbstractItemCheckpoint(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    '''Abstract item checkpoint, derive concrete item checkpoints that verify if a item (Subsystem, Component,
       etc.) is eligible for creating a Task for it.'''

    @abstractmethod
    def convert(self):
        '''
        Ensure that model inheriting from AbstractItemCheckpoint has convert method.
        '''
        pass
```

This could ensure that any class like `Employee` or `Department` has to have `convert` method, thus making it safer to be submitted to instance of `Converter`.

Comment: Appreciate you for detailed response. I can't create for Employees and Departments single classe, because both of these would be wrapped by my SOAP service as returned type. I'm prejunior programmer :) And I need to know how I can realise DRY principle here.

Comment: @AlGiorgio In that case inheritance from a common superclass like above might be the most practical and correct option for you today. Incidentally, that's DRY, or "don't repeat yourself": you do not create redundant code this way but put it in a common class, creating 2 convert methods because there is little reasonable possibility to have it common without overcomplicating it and mixing up logic of Employee and Department (which even if possible would be violation of SRP)